# Calling functions PHP

Tags: php

Look at the code below:

```
function big() {
    function small() {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
    // I want to call the function here
}
```

How would I call `small()` where the comment is?

Comment: It should work. as long as at some point you call `big();`.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? If I just type `small()` it will echo `Hello World!`?

Comment: Why do you want to define functions in functions? Why not declare both functions on the same level?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call `big();` and you should be set:

```
function big() {
    function small() {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
    small();
}

big();
```

Note that this is probably a poor design and you shouldn't do this.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot (though I did try and it said you have to wait `x` minutes until you can)!

Comment: @Druzion - I noticed you unaccepted, did this not answer your question?

Comment: Well, I thought it was solved like this, however my code was not working. It turned out to be some other problem, so I was going to delete this question (since it is so simple and will probably not help anyone at all in the future). However, you can if it has no accepted answers, or answers with upvotes. I un-accepted it so I can delete it, but now I see the vote counts and it turns out it has been upvoted.